# Jenkins on Debian not accessible via Browser

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, jenkins

I installed Jenkins on a remote server running Debian 6.0.6 with a ready-to-use Apache 2 instance by using the following instructions:

```
wget -q -O - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | apt-key add -
sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
apt-get update
apt-get install jenkins
```

Then I did some configuration:

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod vhost_alias
```

I created the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/jenkins`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.de/jenkins
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass /jenkins http://mydomain.de:8080/jenkins
</VirtualHost>
```

And finally restarted Apache with `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

Now I cannot reach it via Webbrowser. Neither of the following lines works:

```
mydomain.de/jenkins
mydomain.de:8080
mydomain.de:8080/jenkins
```

Using the first address triggers the following error message in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
File does not exist: /var/www/main/jenkins
```

EDIT: I just found out that starting the browser on the remote server I can access Jenkins by visiting `http://localhost:8080`. So Jenkins works, only the redirection is still erroneous.

Comment: I don't think you can use `ServerName mydomain.de/jenkins` maybe set it up as `jenkins.mydomain.de` with the proper DNS entry..

Comment: Well I used a [guide for hudson](http://www.zzorn.net/2009/11/setting-up-hudson-on-port-80-on-debian.html) like [another guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446352/cannot-access-jenkins) in this forum did.

Comment: You didn't read it very well, nowhere in that hudson guide does it say to put a `ServerName` directive like you have used. Get rid of the `/jenkins` at the end, just type it in yourself in the browser.

Comment: Thank you, you were right! Actually I used serveral guides which is why the configuration got mixed up a bit. Do you know where to start if I want to use `jenkins.mydomain.de`?

Comment: Well, first set up a DNS entry, an A record under yourdomain.de, then use the proxypass directive like this `ProxyPass / http://mydomain.de:8080/jenkins` or something similar.

Comment: Are there any reason not to use `mod_ajp` instead of `mod_proxy`?  Jetty, which I belive is what are used in Jenkins stand alone Java Container mode, do have support for AJP and so do Apache2.
(sorry if it is belived to be OT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ServerName Directive
>
> Description:  Hostname and port that the server uses to identify itself
>   Syntax:   ServerName **[scheme://]fully-qualified-domain-name[:port]**
>   Context:  server config, virtual host Status: Core Module:    core

You do not need, in fact cannot use, a directory as part of a FQDN.

From Wikipedia:

> A fully qualified domain name (FQDN), sometimes also referred as an
>   absolute domain name,[1] is a domain name that specifies its exact
>   location in the tree hierarchy of the Domain Name System (DNS). It
>   specifies all domain levels, including the top-level domain and the
>   root zone.[2]